# Zip two lists of unequal length to form a dictionary. Values to be randomly picked from one of the lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

[Using Python 3.x] I'm trying to create a CSV file with two columns, one containing fake e-mail addresses, the second column should contain a certain country code as specified in the respective function.

I would like the country codes to be - at least - uniformly distributed assigned to each e-mail address. But it would be great if there was also a way that they were not uniformly distributed. For instance where one country could would be assigned to 30% of the e-mail addresses, another one 10%, etc.

My biggest struggle is with creating a dictionary where the key is the e-mail address and the value the country code, and thus zipping two lists that have unequal length and not having empty values (None). On a side note, I thought creating a dictionary would be the best way to do so, but I'm very new to programming and python and hence if you have a better solution please do share!!

This is my code:

```
from random import choice, randint
from string import ascii_lowercase
from itertools import zip_longest
import csv

def gen_name(length):
    """"Generates a random name with the given amount of characters."""
    return ''.join(choice(ascii_lowercase) for i in range(length))

def email_gen():
    """Generates a fake email address."""
    user = gen_name(randint(5, 10))
    host = gen_name(randint(5, 15))
    return user + "@" + host + ".com"

def gen_plain_email_list(n):
    """Generates a list of n amount of random e-mail addresses"""
    emaillist = []
    for i in range(n):
        emaillist.append(email_gen())
    return emaillist

def gen_email_dict(n):
    """Generates a dictionary where the key is an e-mail address and the value a random country code."""
    email_list = []
    cc = ['us', 'gb', 'de', 'fr', 'it', 'nl', 'es', 'ae', 'br', 'au']

    # Creating a list of n amount of e-mail addresses
    for i in range(n):
        email_list.append(email_gen())
    # Creates dictionary with with an e-mail address from email_list and
    # a random country code from the cc list
    email_dict = dict(zip_longest(email_list, cc, fillvalue=choice(cc)))
    return email_dict

def dict_to_csv(filename, n):
    with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f)
        w.writerows(gen_email_dict(n).items())

dict_to_csv('test.csv', 1000)
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have percentages per country code, simply expand the countries list until you have enough elements, then shuffle the list:

```
cc = [('us', .2), ('gb', .2), ('de', .1), ('fr', .05), ('it', .05)]
distribution = n / sum(dist for c, dist in cc)
countries = []
for c, dist in cc:
    countries.extend([c] * int(round(distribution * dist)))
# rounding errors may mean we have too few, add until we have enough
while len(countries) < n:
    countries.append(random.choice(cc)[0])
random.shuffle(countries)
```

Now you can zip these with your email addresses, with the countries distributed evenly according to their weights.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, this does do what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to **abuse** the `zip` function. In your case using a genexp or dict-comprehension is straightforward:

```
def gen_email_dict(n):
    return {get_email(): choice(cc) for _ in range(n)}
    #return dict((get_email(), choice(cc)) for _ in range(n))  # python2
```

The `zip` function should be used only with sequences of equal length, while `zip_longest` allows not equal length, but the default value is not a function that can produce arbitrary values!

If you really want to use `zip`, a way for doing this is to have an infinite country code generator:

```
cc = ['us', 'gb', 'de', 'fr', 'it', 'nl', 'es', 'ae', 'br', 'au']
def _countries():
    while True:
        yield choice(cc)

countries = _countries()

def gen_email_dict(n):
    # using zip_longest you'll get an infinite loop!!!
    return dict(zip((gen_email() for _ in range(n)), countries))
    # using itertools.islice you wont get an infinite loop.
    # but there is no reason to complicate things.
    #return dict(zip_longest((gen_email() for _ in range(n)), it.islice(countries, n)))
```

Comment: Thanks Bakuriu, this worked like a charm! I did not specifically want to us (or **abuse**) the `zip` function, like I said I'm quite new to this so I did not know of any other way.

Answer (score 0):

To randomly select country codes with different probabilities, you could create a set of weights that can be used to generate a universe from which you randomly select a code. I'm using Python 2 here, but the general idea is the same:

```
emails = [chr(65 + i) + '@foo.bar' for i in range(26)]

cc_weights = dict(
    us = 5,
    gb = 3,
    de = 2,
)

# A universe of country codes, based on the weighting we defined.
ccs = sum(([c] * n for c,n in cc_weights.iteritems()), [])

email_ccs = dict((e, choice(ccs)) for e in emails)
```